# Not able to get Open Telemetry data into Elastic APM

Tags: elastic-stack, elastic-apm

Not able to get Open Telemetry data into elastic APM. I have followed all the details as per documentation as below:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry-direct.html#instrument-apps-otel

My java weblogic server application deployed on linux server. I want to send the data to APM server located in "apmserver" which is up and running. so exported below:

```
export OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER="otlp"
export OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER="otlp"
export OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER="otlp"
export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://apmserver:8200
EXPORT OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=myappservice,service.version=1.1,deployment.environment=QA
```

I have added start-up arguments to my jvm for agent as below:

```
-javaagent:opt/trade/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
```

Started the server and did some Transactions on my App. No data being collected under Onservability--Services? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything immediately obvious here -- would you mind posting over on discuss.elastic.co instead? It is more friendly to the back and forth debugging model.